# W2UI edit inline does not work with infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, w2ui

Good morning, I tried the example of w2ui infinity scroll, 
but by adding the 
property: editable columns is produced an error. 
Can someone help me ?
Thank you.

```
<div id="main" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
// widget configuration
 var config = {
  grid: { 
    name: 'grid',
    url : 'getDati.php',
    autoLoad: false,
    show: { 
        footer    : true,
        toolbar    : true
    },
      columns: [                
            ...
    searchable: 'text', resizable: true, editable: { type: 'text' } },
           { field: 'date', caption: 'Date', size: '200px', resizable: true, 
     sortable: true, editable: { type: 'date', format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }  }
        ]
   ...
   }
  };


      $(function () {
          $('#main').w2grid(config.grid);
      });
       </script>

    errore

        - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'w2ui' of undefined
        - at w2grid.dblClick (w2ui-1.5.rc1.js:6609)
        - at w2grid.click (w2ui-1.5.rc1.js:5928)
        - at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick (test.php:1)
```